# Find previous unique value in a Dataframe - Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with multiple products for each date by customer. In a new column I am trying to get previous unique date by customer.

```
Cst Prod    Dt  Desired Output
C1  P1  1-Jan-16    0
C1  P2  1-Jan-16    0
C1  P3  1-Jan-16    0
C1  P4  1-Jan-16    0
C1  P1  20-Jan-16   1-Jan-16
C1  P2  20-Jan-16   1-Jan-16
C2  P2  5-Feb-17    0
C2  P3  5-Feb-17    0
C2  P4  5-Feb-17    0
C2  P1  30-Mar-17   5-Feb-17
```

I am just starting with PySpark. So far, I tried creating an array column of dates (CUM_DATE) for each customer and then applying UDF to get all dates except one in the row and then take max of array column.

Something on the lines of -

```
def filter_currdate(arr, dt):
    return [x for x in arr if x not in dt]

filter_currdate_udf = F.udf(lambda x: filter_code(x), ArrayType(DateType()))

df = df.withColumn('except_date', filter_currdate_udf(df['CUM_DATE'], df['Dt']))
df = df.withColumn('max_prev_date',F.max(df['except_date']))
```

But it is running into error and I am unable to figure out a better way to get this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is other way without custom UDF functions. Let say `df` has columns `cst`, `prod`, `dt`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
df.alias('df1').join(df.alias('df2'), 
( 
   col('df1.cst')==col('df2.cst') 
 & col('df1.prod') == col('df2.prod')
 & col('df1.dt') > col('df2.dt'),
 how='left_outer'
).select('df1.*', 'df2.dt')
.groupBy('df1.cst', 'df1.prod', 'df1.dt')
.agg(max('df2.dt'))
```